# pgadmin queries not executed

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Suddenly my queries in pgAdmin (ver. 7.2) don't return any results.  In the Data Output window I get the error:

> No data output.  Execute a query to get output.

It was working earlier today.  I can right click on the table and edit the first 100 rows and that works fine. I'm just doing a `select * from myTable;`.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it's working today.  Maybe an issue with the server itself?  I don't know.